# Show nav dependant on mouse coordinates

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, client

I've found this JS fiddle, which does exactly what I'm looking for. However, I can't seem to figure out how to get it to work when I move the navigation to the side.

```
var hoverMenu = $('#HiddenMenu'),
hoverSpace = $('#HoverSpace');
hoverSpace.on('mousemove', function(event) {
if(35 - event.clientY < 0) {
    hoverMenu.css({top: 35 - event.clientY});
} else {
    hoverMenu.css({top: 0});
}
}).on('mouseout', function() {
hoverMenu.css({top: -35});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PaZHH/1/ <-- this is working example of the clientX/Y event I'm wanting

I can't seem to implement this by using clientX & moving the navigation to the right hand side.

This is where I managed to get too http://jsfiddle.net/PaZHH/102/

Comment: What exactly do you want? The navigation to show from where? To the opposite side of your example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make this changes.
Add absolute positioning to hidden menu:

```
#HiddenMenu {
    background-color: #e00;
    position: absolute;
    right: -35px;
}
```

Make the hover space position relative:

```
#HoverSpace {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #aeaeae;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 45px;
    height: 500px;
}
```

Now, you'll be fine. You can check the result [here](http://jsfiddle.net/PaZHH/104/). It currently works by moving in from right, which is a bit different from you horizontal sample.

Comment: when i position the hoverspace to right, using float: right; it doesn't quite do what I want? Check http://jsfiddle.net/PaZHH/105/

Comment: I'm wanting it to slide out from the right & display within the hoverspace. then slide back to offscreen when mouse isn't within hoverspace

Comment: @Minum As you are changing the position of the container, using the raw mouse position won't help. You'll need to use the starting X of the container, too. I've changed the jsfiddle a bit, see how it works [here](http://jsfiddle.net/PaZHH/112/).

Comment: Thank you, this is the effect I'm going for! Just played around with the css a little to get it working exactly how I wanted! Thanks heaps!